# How to include ActionMailer class in rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, rake-task

I want to use ActionMailer in my rake task in order to send emails to people at a particular time.

I have written a mailer class in app/mailers folder like this:

```
class AlertsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'x@y.com'

  def mail_alert(email_addresses, subject, url)
    @url  = '#{url}'
    mail(to: email_addresses, subject: 'Alert') do |format|
      format.html { render '/alerts/list' }
    end
  end
end
```

Then I included the following line in my rake task:

```
AlertsMailer.mail_alert(email_addresses, subject)
```

When I try to run the rake task:

```
rake update_db
```

I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant AlertsMailer
```

I think I have to somehow load the mailer class in my rake task, but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the following and it is working:

```
# in lib/tasks/mailme.rake
task :mailme => :environment do
  UserMailer.test_email(1).deliver
end
```

And

```
# in app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_email(user_id)
    @user = User.find_by_id user_id

    if (@user)
      to = @user.email

      mail(:to => to, :subject => "test email", :from => "default_sender@foo.bar") do |format|
        format.text(:content_type => "text/plain", :charset => "UTF-8", :content_transfer_encoding => "7bit")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But how do I include preview of my webpage here in my mail?

Comment: In views/user_mailer/test_email.text.erb in the example above

Answer (score 9):

From your tag, I believe you're using Rails.

You can load your Rails environment by requiring a dependency to the environment task as follows:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
    ...
end
```

instead of

```
task :my_task do
    ...
end
```

Let me know if it helps.